# Nginx return 444 depending on upstream response code

Tags: nginx

I have nginx setup to pass to an upstream using proxy pass.  The upstream is written to return a 502 http response on certain requests, rather then returning the 502 with all the header I would like nginx to recoginse this and return 444 so nothing is returned.  Is this possible?

I also tried to return 444 on any 50x error but it doesn't work either.

```
location / {
    return 444;
}


location ^~ /service/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}

location = /50x.html {
    return 444;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As per the documentation of [error_page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page), it could be done like this...

`error_page  500 502 503 504 =444 /50x.html;`

In the same way...

`error_page  404 =444 /404.html;`

So, your entire sample configuration would become...

```
location / {
    return 444;
}

location ^~ /service/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 =444 /50x.html;
}

error_page  404 =444 /404.html;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, now I get the 444 for everything except when my upstream returns a 502, it just passes back normally to the client.

Answer (score 4):

If the backend is actually returning a 502, and it's not being generated by nginx internally because the backend is unreachable, then you'll need to turn on [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_intercept_errors) for your error_page directive to take effect.